# Trapezoidal Kernel for convolution without Astropy

Tags: python-3.x, astropy

I am trying to implement a trapezoidal kernel in python for convolution. Is there a way to do convolution as it is done in the astropy module :**Trapezoid1DKernel(*width*,*slope*)** by using it's trapezoidal kernel?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same query at some point of time. There is no way to implement a kernel but instead a trapezoidal wave can be generated and then you can proceed with the convolution part. I achieved it by using this:

```
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import numpy as np

def trapzoid_signal(t, width=2., slope=1., amp=1., offs=0):
    a = slope*width*signal.sawtooth(2*np.pi*t/width, width=0.5)/4.
    a += slope*width/4.
    a[a>amp] = amp
    return a + offs

for w,s,a in zip([32],[1],[0.0322]):
    t = np.linspace(0, w, 34)

    plt.plot(t,trapzoid_signal(t, width=w, slope=s, amp=a))


plt.show()
```

The result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RkBF.png

(The width and slope values are exactly the same so as to generate a trapezoidal waveform same as the trapezoidal kernel of astropy). Hope this helps.